# I am unable to log the variable outside the callback function which is assigned with values inside it in Android

Tags: java, android

This is the function where I am assigning a value to my variable `Place`:

```java
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //check LocationPermission Granted
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                try {
                    // This is the place where I am storing my lanlag object
                    place = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "null refrence in result", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Here I am trying to log
    Log.i("land and lon", String.valueOf(place.latitude)+" "+String.valueOf(place.longitude));
}
```

Comment: I suspect the issue is that the variable is still null at the time you are logging it. The callback function won't run until after the outer function that set it up returns to the main loop.

Comment: What is it logging and what do you expect it to look like?

Comment: Similar to other comments - move your `Log.i` to just after the `place` assignment in `onSuccess` - it runs as a callback asychronously.